# CakePHP 2.2.2 bake for plugin

Tags: cakephp-2.1

I am trying to bake models, controllers and views for my plugin in my app called: admin. I am using windows 7. Bake works when baking an app and within the app.

This is what I am doing:

1. cd c:\wamp\www\propharm\app (also tried without \app)
2. cake bake plugin admin model

This is the folder my plugin resides in: C:\wamp\www\propharm\app\Plugin

I get this in response from the console.

```
Create the directory structure, AppModel and AppController classes for a
new plugin. Can create plugins in any of your bootstrapped plugin paths.

Usage:
cake bake plugin [-h] [-v] [-q] [<name>]

Options:

--help, -h     Display this help.
--verbose, -v  Enable verbose output.
--quiet, -q    Enable quiet output.

Arguments:

name  CamelCased name of the plugin to create.
      (optional)
```

I tried this:
in bootrap.php

```
CakePlugin::load('Admin');
```

Its still not working. If someone knows what I am doing wrong, please help. thanks. 
Louis

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Bake your plugin:

```
cake bake plugin PluginNameInCamelCase
```

2) Bake everything else:

```
cake bake controller ControllerName --plugin PluginNameInCamelCase
```

See this page for further documentation in baking plugins: [Creating Your Own Plugins with CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#creating-your-own-plugins)

Comment: cake bake all ModelName --plugin PluginNameInCamelCase doesn't work

Comment: I assume it's because it needs to be: `cake bake model ModelName --plugin PluginNameInCamelCase` and NOT `cake bake all...`

Comment: i do **model** first and **all** next... but **all** doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Although above code works but this code provide more useful options.

Step 1: Create Plugin

> cake bake plugin PluginNameInCamelCase

Step 2: Create Model

> cake bake model plugin --PluginNameInCamelCase`

It will show list of available models, select you want to bake like user model, news model etc

Step 3: Create Controller

> cake bake controller plugin -- PluginNameInCamelCase

It will show list of available controllers, select you want to bake like user controller, news controller etc

Step 4: create finally view files for your plugin

> cake bake view plugin --PluginNameInCamelCase

It will show list of available controllers for which you want to make view files, select and done!

[Read more](http://a2znotes.blogspot.com/2014/11/code-generation-with-cakephp-creating-plugin.html)